# $$hashKey must not start with '$' Deployd

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, deployd

Hi when i post to deployd i get this strange error in console

```
Object {name: "MongoError", message: "key $$hashKey must not start with '$'", status: 400}
```

code

```
 dpd.timesheetsdone.post({
      "projectId": $scope.projectId ,
      "formandSig":  $scope.signature,
      "timesheets": $scope.timesheets

    }, function (result, err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log(result, result.id);
    });
```

project id and signature is a simple string, timesheets is an array

if i replace scope.timesheets with

```
  [
    {
        "projectId": "1000",
        "date": "2015-05-15T22:00:00.000Z",
        "start": "25200"
    }
]
```

it works..

onsole.log(scope.timesheet...  returns an object with same values + and hash key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed hash key parseing timesheets to JSON 
Dont know if this is the right / best way to remove hash keys?

```
      $scope.sign = function() {
   var sheets = angular.toJson($scope.timesheets);
   var sheets = JSON.parse(sheets);
    dpd.timesheetsdone.post({
      "projectId": $scope.projectId ,
      "formandSig":  $scope.signature,
      "timesheets": sheets

    }, function (result, err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log(result, result.id);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Angular automatically adds `$$hashKey` to all objects within your `$scope.timesheets` array. You can get rid of these by doing `angular.toJson($scope.timesheets)`

so your post would look like this:

```
 dpd.timesheetsdone.post({
  "projectId": $scope.projectId ,
  "formandSig":  $scope.signature,
  "timesheets": angular.toJson($scope.timesheets)
  ...
```

Comment: seems to work but now i get a new error Object {message: "Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined", status: 400}
on my deployd i got this.timesheets.forEach.... on post

Comment: You have to decode JSON back by using ```JSON.parse(this.timesheets)``` on your Deployd code

Comment: mm this gives me Object {message: "Unexpected token u", status: 400}